# How can I convert an ISO8601 timestamp into unix time in Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime, unix-timestamp, iso8601

Given a string that represents a date/time in ISO8601 format (e.g. `20100723T073000`), I need to ultimately parse this into a user-supplied format using a general `strftime` format string. In order to do that, I need to convert the ISO8601 timestamp to a Unix timestamp. There are a huge amount of date/time manipulation modules for Perl and I'm a little overwhelmed. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The champion module for handling dates, times, durations, timezones and formats is [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime).  Once you've got your DateTime object, you can perform a huge number of operations on it, like adding/subtracting other DateTime objects or [DateTime::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Duration) objects, or printing it out in another format.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;

my $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime('20100723T073000');

print $dt->strftime('%F %T');
```

prints: "2010-07-23 07:30:00"

Answer (score 7):

If you don't have or don't want to install the `DateTime::Format::ISO8601` module, you can parse at least a subset of ISO8601 with `HTTP::Date`:

```
$ perl -MHTTP::Date -wle 'print str2time("2013-11-30T23:05:03")'
1385845503
```

As with any date handling, be cautious about time zone issues.